# Video posting to Facebook wall

Tags: facebook-graph-api, ios5

How to post a recorded video into Facebook wall with message and please tell me is there any possibility for posting a video into Facebook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this article :[How-To: Use the Graph API to Upload a Video (iOS)](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/532/)

```
- (void)fbDidLogin {
    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sample" ofType:@"mov"];
    NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   videoData, @"video.mov",
                                   @"video/quicktime", @"contentType",
                                   @"Video Test Title", @"title",
                                   @"Video Test Description", @"description",
                       nil];
    [facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/videos"
                         andParams:params
                     andHttpMethod:@"POST"
                       andDelegate:self];
}
```